# Calculating subtotals using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, subtotal

How do I go about fetching from (or writing to) input fields relative to $(this) in a form?

I wish to loop through all input fields "antal" and calculate subtotals based on "antal" multiplied by the price relative to "antal" and store the calculated price in a subtotal input field relative to "antal".

A full pen here http://codepen.io/Ktraving/pen/RKRGQG

```
$("input").change(function(){
    var subtot=0;
    var total=0;

    $("input[name=antal]").each(function(){                                             
       subtot = subtot + (parseInt($(this).val()) * $("input[name=pris]").val());
        $("input[name=subpris]").val(subtot);                                           
    });

    /* Totalling the subtotals */

    $("input[name=subpris]").each(function(){
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $("input[name=totpris]").val(total);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `closest()` to go up to the parent then find the related input with name `pris/subpris` :

```
$(this).closest('div').find("input[name=pris]").val();
```

**NOTE :** No need for `each()` just calculate the sub total of the current input `antal`, also I suggest the use of `input` instead of `change` when you track the field.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='antal']").on('input', function(){
    var subtot=0;
    var total=0;
    var parent = $(this).closest('.maling_rekke');
    var pris = parent.find("input[name=pris]").val();

    subtot += parseInt($(this).val()) * pris;
    parent.find("input[name=subpris]").val(subtot);

    $("input[name=subpris]").each(function(){    
      total = total + parseInt($(this).val());   
    });

    $("input[name=totpris]").val(total);     
  });
});
```

```css
/* Overordnet styling */
* 
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0vw;
  padding:0vw;
}

fieldset
{
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border-color:red;
  border-width:5px;
  background:#eee;
}

legend
{
  margin-left:15px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

/* Overordnet ramme, der på sigt kan benytte flexbox for at gøre formularen responsiv */

.flex_ramme 
{
  width: 500px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color: white;
  margin:30px 30px 30px 30px;
}


/* Styling af formular og felter til formularen */


.maling_rekke
{
  padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;
  clear:both;
}

.maling_felt
{
  padding:5px;
  max-width:80vw;
}

.maling_billede
{
  height:100px;
}

.maling_ramme
{
  float:left;
  min-width:130px;
  max-width:30vw;
  height:200px;
  padding-right:10px;
}




/* Styling af afsluttende knapper */

.knapper
{
  float:right;
}

#knap_nulstil
{
  margin-right:20px;
  background-color: #CC3230; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

#knap_nulstil:hover
{
  transition: background-color 0.8s ease;
  background-color:#ff3230; 
}


#knap_bestil
{
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#knap_bestil:hover
{
  transition: background-color 0.8s ease;
  background-color: #4CDF50; /* Green */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex_ramme">

  <form action="send_bestilling.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>

      <legend>Bestilling af maling</legend>

      <div class="maling_rekke">
        <div class="maling_ramme">
          <img class="maling_billede maling_felt" src="spand.jpg" alt="Maling type A">
        </div>
        <p class="maling_type maling_felt">Sigma S2U Satin - slidstærk</p>
        <p class="maling_pris">100 kr.</p><input type="hidden" name="pris" value="100">
        <p class="maling_felt">Antal:</p> <input class="maling_input maling_felt" type="text" name="antal" value="0"><br>
        <p class="maling_felt">Subtotal (inkl. moms):</p> <input class="maling_sub maling_felt" type="text" name="subpris" value="0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="maling_rekke">
        <div class="maling_ramme">
          <img class="maling_billede maling_felt" src="spand2.jpg" alt="Maling type A">
        </div>
        <p class="maling_type maling_felt">Yunik Træmaling</p>
        <p class="maling_pris">200 kr.</p><input type="hidden" name="pris" value="200">        
        <p class="maling_felt">Antal:</p> <input class="maling_input maling_felt" type="text" name="antal" value="0"><br>
        <p class="maling_felt">Subtotal (inkl. moms):</p> <input class="maling_sub maling_felt" type="text" name="subpris" value="0" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="maling_rekke">
        <div class="maling_ramme">
          <img class="maling_billede maling_felt" src="spand3.jpg" alt="Maling type A">
        </div>
        <p class="maling_type maling_felt">Yunik Radiatormaling</p>
        <p class="maling_pris">300 kr.</p><input type="hidden" name="pris" value="300">        
        <p class="maling_felt">Antal:</p> <input class="maling_input maling_felt" type="text" name="antal" value="0"><br>
        <p class="maling_felt">Subtotal (inkl. moms):</p> <input class="maling_sub maling_felt" type="text" name="subpris" value="10" readonly>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

      <legend>Godkendt bestilling</legend>

      <div class="maling_rekke">
        Total (inkl. moms): <input class="maling_totalt maling_felt" type="text" name="totpris" value="0" readonly> DKK.</br>
      <input class="maling_felt" type="checkbox" name="godkend" value="Bike">Jeg godkender hermed bestillingen<br>    
      </div>

    </fieldset>

  <div class="knapper">

    <input id="knap_nulstil" type="reset" value="Nulstil">
    <input id="knap_bestil" type="submit" value="Send bestilling">

  </div>

  </form>

</div> <!-- Slut anden flexramme -->
```